# Word for Mac - recover document?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, file-recovery

I created two Word docs on my Mac last week (tens of pages long - each of them).  I emailed them to my client on Thursday through a GMail account.  There is zero chance I didn't hit "save" multiple times during that process, and I thought I was saving them to a jump drive.  They were still open this morning when I installed the latest OS update (requiring a restart).  It asked me if I wanted to save the changes for each of them - I clicked "don't save" because I was certain I'd already saved them.  Now I can't find a version older than 8/18 (and I completed/mailed them on 8/24).  I have Time Machine - and it isn't finding them either.  They *must* be somewhere on the computer - I just can't find them.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you sent the docs as an attachment via Gmail, why not just check your Sent Mail folder in Gmail?